# A more readable request spec that changes model count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following rspec request spec example which passes

```
it "increases count by 1" do
  attributes = attributes_for(:district)
  expect { post admin_districts_path, params: { district: attributes} }.to change { District.count }.by(1)
end
```

The `expect` line is a little busy, so I'm trying to break it up.  The following causes an error

```
it "increases count by 1" do
  attributes = attributes_for(:district)
  block = { post admin_districts_path, params: { district: attributes} }
  expect(block).to change { District.count }.by(1)
end
```

with error

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
```

Why is this error happening?  Is there a cleaner way to write this spec example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, you can create a lambda:

```
block = -> { post admin_districts_path, params: { district: attributes} }
expect(block).to change { District.count }.by(1)
```

Answer (score 6):

I usually run into this kind of long lines in tests. Instead of creating new variables just to improve reading, what I do is to split it into different lines like this:

```
it "increases count by 1" do
  attributes = attributes_for(:district)
  expect do
    post admin_districts_path, params: { district: attributes}
  end.to change { District.count }.by(1)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create a little helper method within the relevant `describe` block. This is taken from a sample rails request spec, and I'm assuming you have FactoryBot set up. Something like this:

```
describe "create /district" do
    def create_district_request
      @district = build(:district)
      params = {district: {name: @district.name etc.}}
      post district_path, params: params
    end    

    it "creates a district" do
      expect {create_district_request}.to change{District.count}.by(1)
    end
end
```

Hope it helps.